# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro?

Tags: java, ios, android-studio, flutter

I'm getting this error when trying to launch my app on Iphone. How do i fix it?

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_next' in:
        /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-awmjwtlfwtwzmhcficfyhoavvpwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common 2.o
        /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-awmjwtlfwtwzmhcficfyhoavvpwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_begin' in:
        /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-awmjwtlfwtwzmhcficfyhoavvpwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common 2.o
        /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-awmjwtlfwtwzmhcficfyhoavvpwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_find' in:

    ld: 35 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator. 
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

Comment: Have you check your project's directory? There may be some duplicated files so you got the duplicate symbol compile error?

Comment: hi zhoujialei how can i fix this?

Comment: If it's flutter project I suggest you upload your demo to github somehow. That'll be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found that this worked.

1 - Update Xcode.

2 - Upgrade flutter to the latest version in your terminal: flutter upgrade

3 - Update cocoa pods with: $ sudo gem install cocoapods

4 - In Android studio terminal run: flutter clean & then flutter run

After that, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue. I was following a YT intro to **flutter/dart/ios** debugging live via simulator.

Turns out I required to update flutter and its related files.

I just ran `flutter upgrade --force`. I believe this overwrites any previously saved settings so maybe back-up your work prior to this forced upgrade. However, after running this and updating everything it worked fine for me again.